# Adjektive auf -lich und -haft

Tags: adjective-ending

Existiert eine leichte Erklärung, wie man die Adjektive auf -lich und -haft unterscheiden kann? Zum Beispiel: warum sagt man "eine schmerzliche Erfahrung" aber demgegenüber "eine schmerzhafte Verletzung"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eine "leichte" Erklärung? Eher nicht. Aber eine Erklärung schon (in einer alten Grammatik von 1828 gefunden, daher ein bißchen "altmodisch"):

> Die Nachsilbe "-lich" zeigt an:
>
> 1. Die wirkliche Anwesenheit des Zustandes, welchen das Zustandswort angibt. z.B. das, was sich schickt, heißt *schicklich*;
> 2. Eine Verrichtung der Handlung, welche das Stammwort anzeigt, z.B. ein Besuch, der hindert, ist ein *hinderlicher* Besuch;
> 3. Was wirklich getan wird oder getan zu werden verdient, z.B. ein Mensch, der Verachtung verdient, ist ein *verächtlicher* Mensch; [Diese Verwendung gibt es heute für *verächtlich eigentlich nicht mehr - Das Wort bedeutet heute eher "Verachtung ausdrückend"]
> 4. was zu tun möglich oder leicht ist, z.B. was leicht begriffen werden kann, ist *begreiflich*;
> 5. Eine Ähnlichkeit, z.B. was dem Schwarzen ähnlich ist, ist *schwärzlich*;
> 6. Ein Hervorbringen dessen, was das Stammwort anzeigt, z.B. was Abscheu erzeugt, ist *abscheulich*;
> 7. eine Art und Weise, z.B. das Kind hat das Gedicht *wörtlich* auswendig gelernt.
>
> Die Nachsilbe *-haft* bedeutet:
>
> 1. so viel als mit dem versehen oder behaftet, was das Stammwort anzeigt, z.B. wer Tugend besitzt, ist *tugendhaft*;
> 2. so viel als geneigt zu dem, was das Stammwort anzeigt, z.B. wer Neigung zu Lügen hat, heißt *lügenhaft*;  [Meine Anmerkung: dieses Wort gibt es heute nicht mehr. Ich würde hier als Beispiel *Laster* und *lasterhaft* verwenden]
> 3. so viel als erregend oder bewirkend, z.B. ein Anblick, der Ekel verursacht, heißt *ekelhaft*;
> 4. so viel als Ähnlichkeit habend, z.B. eine Arbeit, welche mit der Arbeit eines Meisters Ähnlichkeit hat, heißt *meisterhaft*.

Vieles von dem, was dieses Buch schreibt, ist sicherlich diskutierbar, und einen richtig greifbaren Unterschied zwischen "-lich" und "-haft" kann man sich nur insofern daraus erarbeiten, dass "-lich" wohl eher eine "ist-so-ähnlich-wie" oder "wird getan oder wirkt wie"-Beziehung ausdrückt und "-haft" eher eine "hat die Eigenschaft"-Beziehung. (Das kann man schön an *lästerlich* ("lästernd, als Lästerung empfunden") und *lasterhaft* ("neigt zu Lastern") erkennen.

Und es gibt dabei natürlich sich überschneidende Bedeutungen - Zwischen "meisterlich" und "meisterhaft" kann ich z.B. keinen entscheidenden Unterschied erkennen (Der Duden führt sie als Synonyme).

Das Buch, von dem ich denke, dass es kaum jemand haben dürfte, heißt "Deutsche Sprachlehre für Lehrende und Lernende" von Michael Desaga aus 1828.

Comment: Tausend Dank für Ihre Hilfe und die genommene Zeit!

Comment: Gegenbeispiel: *jugendlich* – wirklich jung. *jugendhaft* – wirkt (gekünstelt) jung.

Comment: @tofro   Würdest du noch das Buch genauer bezeichnen? Das wäre bei so einer schönen Quelle doch angebracht!

Comment: @tofro  Inhaltliche Frage: Würdest du der Einschätzung des Autors von 1828 folgen? Oder könnte man auch einen für Grammatiker nicht untypischen Versuch einer Übersystematisierung latent unsystematischer Sprachphänomene vermuten? Immerhin ist das hier ja fast ein Lehrbeispiel für Regeln, die komplizierter sind als die von ihnen beschriebene Wirklichkeit, will sagen: Man lernt leichter die Wörter selbst als die Regeln dazu.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich denke ja, das ist ein schönes Beispiel für krampfhaftes Regelnsuchen, deshalb hab' ich es abgeschrieben.

Comment: @Janka *jugendhaft* ist mir allerhöchstens aus dem Strafvollzug bekannt. Aber dann wäre es großgeschrieben.

Comment: *Diese Vorstellung war doch sehr jugendhaft.* (im Sinne von *laienhaft*, aber netter.) Was du meinst, heißt *Jugendarrest*.

Comment: @Janka „jugendhaft“ kennt mein Wörterbuch nicht. „Jugendhaft“ schon. Bist du sicher, dass du das nicht mit „jungenhaft“ verwechselst?

Comment: Ja, da bin ich mir sehr sicher. Das Wörter nicht im Wörterbuch drinstehen ist ja nix neues.

Answer (score 0):

Neben dem Jahr 1828 ist in diesem Zusammenhang unter Umständen auch das Jahr 2018 von Interesse.

[**-haft**](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_haft)

> drückt in Bildungen mit Substantiven aus, dass die beschriebene Person
>   oder Sache vergleichbar mit jemandem, etwas oder so geartet wie
>   jemand, etwas ist
>
> *Beispiele:* babyhaft, bruchstückhaft, romanhaft

[**-lich**](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_lich)

> **(1)** kennzeichnet in Bildungen mit Substantiven die Zugehörigkeit zu
>   diesen
>
> *Beispiele:* baulich, grundgesetzlich, programmlich
>
> **(2a)** drückt in Bildungen mit Verben (Verbstämmen) aus, dass mit der beschriebenen Person oder Sache etwas gemacht werden kann
>
> *Beispiele:* bestechlich, erklärlich
>
> **(2b)** verneint in Verbindung mit un-
>
> *Beispiele:* unauflöslich, unauslöschlich
>
> **(3)** drückt in Bildungen mit Verben (Verbstämmen) aus, dass die beschriebene Person oder Sache etwas macht
>
> *Beispiele:* dienlich, einbringlich, einträglich
>
> **(4)** drückt in Bildungen mit Adjektiven eine Abschwächung oder Differenzierung aus
>
> *Beispiele:* dümmlich, gelblich, rundlich
>
> **(5)** drückt in Bildungen mit Substantiven (Zeitangaben) eine Wiederholung aus
>
> *Beispiele:* halbjährlich, stündlich, vierzehntäglich